# Formatting/escaping jsonb attribute names

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

Given a table with **jsonb** field and a list of attribute names. How do I go about formatting a query to select all the attributes in the list?

I have a list with attribute name: **Never say 'Never'**

```sql
create table t(a jsonb);

insert into t values('{ "Never say ''Never''": "I won''t"}'::jsonb);

select a->>'Never say ''Never''' as "Never say 'Never'" from t;
```

Something like that, but no quotes for attribute names:

```js
pgp.as.format(attrs.map((attr, i) => `a->>'$${i}~' as $${i}~`).join(', '), attrs);
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, and provide a clear example of the output that you expect, plus what you have tried.

Comment: You are using `~` for use with quoted names, but asking for a no-quotes version? I don't understand what it is that you really want. You need to clarify your question, and make a simpler example of what you get and what you want.

Comment: Let me rephrase: is there a way to format jsonb attribute names so apostrophes are properly escaped?

Comment: Not sure what properly means in your case, but perhaps the [open-value](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#open-values) filter, if you want those open?

Comment: Great, that worked like I expected. Thank you.